# Installing MySQL on Ubuntu creates kworker/systemd-udevd blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, mysql

I've tested it twice. First time was on Ubuntu 12.04 with MySQL 5.5. Now I've tried it on Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL 5.6. Both were fresh installs.

Right after MySQL finishes installing, I begin to get these messages:

```
[14520.160115] INFO: task kworker/0:1:154 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[14520.163210]       Not tainted 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[14520.166242] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[14520.169550] INFO: task systemd-udevd:5475 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[14520.171973]       Not tainted 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[14520.174406] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

This continues over and over again. Seems strange to not have this documented anywhere as I feel it must be pretty common... I can't think of anything I'm doing differently than other people doing a fresh install of ubuntu and mysql.

Comment: The notices before this task kworker notice are probably important. For instance: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/429321 shows a render error

Comment: @Rinzwind There weren't any notices before that. MySQL finished installing, I logged in (mysql -u root -p) did "show databases;" and then before long these messages started appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help from the [H], I was pointed to the fact that I'm using dynamic memory management in Hyper-V, and that it does not work so well with linux operating systems.

http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1856145

https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/12/2/662

Answer (score 1):

I've found the same issue on a fresh install of 14.04 without MySQL on Hyper V (Win8). As with 12.04, switching to static memory fixed the problem.